# Firebase sometimes doesn't update the values

Tags: reactjs, firebase, transactions

I've been developing a web application with React. Here is a short video where I'm testing a checkbox's true and false value. Once I create a new task and updates the checkbox value from the UI, it doesn't update. It also happens randomly with an other existing task. I'm sure there isn't any code mistake because the task does update sometimes?

Here is the short video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yd1wTCrjdudvsuLRvtlaa4BINblluO1r/view?usp=sharing

```
//State
state = {
    checked: false,
}

//Done state function
async doneState(uid) {
    const { currentUser } = await firebase.auth();
    if (currentUser) {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/Users/${currentUser.uid}/Tasks/${uid}/done`)
        .set(!this.state.checked);
    }
  }

// UI Render
render(){
  return(
  <Checkbox
    style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
    defaultChecked={item.done}
    onChange={() => {
      this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked /* disabled: true */
      });
      this.doneState(item.uid);
    }}
/>
);
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Updated with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly, you are flipping the Checkbox-state (`this.state.checked`) and then flipping the firebase-state after clicking on the Checkbox. But flipping the firebase-state is on basis of the internal Checkbox-state which might have already changed. Both are asynchronous operation, but of course flipping the firebase-state or running the `doneState()` method takes more time then simply flipping the internal state.

So I think this is what happens here:

1. Check Checkbox
2. Internal state (`!this.state.checked`) changes from `false` to `true`
3. Firebase authentication
4. Firebase sets the value from `false` to `!this.state.checked` === `false`

So nothing changes in Firebase.
Try to pass the current state when checking the Checkbox to `doneState()`.

I think this should work:

```
//Done state function with current state property
async doneState(uid, state) {
    const { currentUser } = await firebase.auth();
    if (currentUser) {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/Users/${currentUser.uid}/Tasks/${uid}/done`)
        .set(!state);
    }
  }

// UI Render
render(){
  return(
  <Checkbox
    style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
    defaultChecked={item.done}
    onChange={() => {
      // To be safe here I also changed the order of these commands
      this.doneState(item.uid, this.state.checked);
      this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked /* disabled: true */
      });

    }}
/>
);
```